# Can somebody show an explicit example of a spinor?

Tags: spin-geometry

I've seen a lot of articles of spinors defined using representation theory, Clifford Algebras, etc. But i want to see (if its possible) how a spinor "looks like" and how it changes sign with a 2pi rotation or any aplication.

Comment: If by spinor you mean an element of a Spin group, there are nice matrix representations for $\mathrm{Spin}(3)$ and $\mathrm{Spin}(4)$, occurring by quaternionic tricks.  I believe these show an obvious sign change by a single rotation.

Comment: Here you can see that a vector rotates an angle $\theta$ when the rotation matrix just has half the angle, i.e. $\theta/2$:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2336441/transformation-of-pauli-matrices/2340996#2340996
A spinor is transformed by the rotation matrix and is thus "rotated" half the angle, so it changes sign under a $2\pi$ rotation.

Comment: Any quaternion is a spinor.